# How can I disable time in element plus datetime picker

Tags: vuejs3, datetimepicker, element-plus

I am using element plus DateTimePicker with vue3. how do I disable past time, from today's date. I didn't find any prop for the same

Answer (score 0):

There is a `disabled-date` attribute. As described in docs it is a function determining if a date is disabled with that date as its parameter and should return a Boolean.

That function could look like this:

```
const disabledDate = (time: Date) => {
  // setHours sets it to the beginning of day so it includes today also
  let today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
  return time.getTime() < today
}
```

[Full example](https://element-plus.run/#eyJzcmMvQXBwLnZ1ZSI6Ijx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgPHA+RGF0ZSBwaWNrZXIgd2l0aCBkaXNhYmxlZCBwYXN0IGRhdGVzPC9wPlxuICA8ZWwtZGF0ZS1waWNrZXJcbiAgICB2LW1vZGVsPVwidmFsdWVcIlxuICAgIHR5cGU9XCJkYXRlXCJcbiAgICBwbGFjZWhvbGRlcj1cIlBpY2sgYSBkYXlcIlxuICAgIDpkaXNhYmxlZC1kYXRlPVwiZGlzYWJsZWREYXRlXCJcbiAgLz5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG5cbjxzY3JpcHQgbGFuZz1cInRzXCIgc2V0dXA+XG5pbXBvcnQgeyByZWYgfSBmcm9tICd2dWUnXG5cbmNvbnN0IHZhbHVlID0gcmVmKCcnKVxuXG5jb25zdCBkaXNhYmxlZERhdGUgPSAodGltZTogRGF0ZSkgPT4ge1xuICAvLyBzZXRIb3VycyBzZXRzIGl0IHRvIHRoZSBiZWdpbm5pbmcgb2YgZGF5IHNvIGl0IGluY2x1ZGVzIHRvZGF5IGFsc29cbiAgbGV0IHRvZGF5ID0gbmV3IERhdGUoKS5zZXRIb3VycygwLCAwLCAwLCAwKVxuICByZXR1cm4gdGltZS5nZXRUaW1lKCkgPCB0b2RheVxufVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7fVxufSIsInRzY29uZmlnLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiY29tcGlsZXJPcHRpb25zXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImFsbG93SnNcIjogdHJ1ZSxcbiAgICBcImNoZWNrSnNcIjogdHJ1ZSxcbiAgICBcImpzeFwiOiBcInByZXNlcnZlXCIsXG4gICAgXCJ0YXJnZXRcIjogXCJFU05leHRcIixcbiAgICBcIm1vZHVsZVwiOiBcIkVTTmV4dFwiLFxuICAgIFwibW9kdWxlUmVzb2x1dGlvblwiOiBcIkJ1bmRsZXJcIixcbiAgICBcImFsbG93SW1wb3J0aW5nVHNFeHRlbnNpb25zXCI6IHRydWUsXG4gICAgXCJ0eXBlc1wiOiBbXCJlbGVtZW50LXBsdXMvZ2xvYmFsLmQudHNcIl1cbiAgfSxcbiAgXCJ2dWVDb21waWxlck9wdGlvbnNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidGFyZ2V0XCI6IDMuM1xuICB9XG59XG4iLCJfbyI6e319)

**Update**

If you need to disable time you can use attributes from TimePicker since DateTimePicker is derived from DatePicker and TimePicker.

So your template can look like this:

```
<el-date-picker
  v-model="value"
  type="datetime"
  placeholder="Pick a day & time"
  :disabled-date="disabledDate"
  :disabled-hours="disabledHours"
  :disabled-minutes="disabledMinutes"
  :disabled-seconds="disabledSeconds"
/>
```

Example is [here](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/time-picker.html#limit-the-time-range)

Comment: This only helps in disabling dates, my requirement is to disable past time, so that I should be able to select today date with future time only